# Sql Query in Oracle for customer and calldetails tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am having below 2 tables.

1. customer - having name, address and telphoneNumber columns.
2. CallDetails - having telphoneNumber, callDate, callDuration columns.

I want to get the customer name and address who is getting highest calls between certain start and end dates.

Thanks

Comment: what does this mean: "is getting highest calls" ? (is it largest number of calls?)

Comment: is getting highest calls means the highest number of calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. Its working for me.

```
select CustomerName,Address from Customer
where PhoneNumber IN
    (SELECT PHONENUMBER FROM CallDetails 
    WHERE CallStartTime BETWEEN 'FromDateTime' AND 'ToDateTime'
    GROUP BY PhoneNumber
    having count(1)=(select TOP 1 count(1) from CallDetails 
                WHERE CallStartTime BETWEEN 'FromDateTime' AND 'ToDateTime'
                group by PhoneNumber ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
                )
    )
ORDER BY CustomerName
```